# Django: How to get the truncated portion of "truncatewords"

Tags: django, filter

I'm trying to split a paragraph in half in Django so that I can apply different styling, but can't figure out how to get the second half of the truncation.

To get the first half I'm using:

```
   <p class="leader">{{ post.body|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
```

The second half will be something like

```
   <p>{{ post.body|truncatewords?? }}</p>  <!-- need to get 30 - end -->
```

I'm sure there's an easy way - Let me know if anyone knows how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: very helpful answer below, but forcing <p "style = .."> within the post and using the {{post|safe} filter ended up being easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy, ask on SO :)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def truncatedwords(value, arg):
    return " ".join(value.split()[arg:])
```

Quick test:

```
>>> def truncatedwords(value, arg):
...     return " ".join(value.split()[arg:])
... 
>>> value = "This is the second part"
>>> arg = 3
>>> truncatedwords(value, arg)
'second part'
>>>
```

All you need to know is in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at Django source. Truncatewords lives at:
`django.template.defaultfilters` and uses `django.utils.text.Truncator`

Comment: @user3279773 did this answer your question? Feedback appreciated!