# Django: How to get the truncated portion of “truncatewords” most directly?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am new to Django. I'm trying to split a title into multiple lines depending on it's length so I can style the subsequent lines appropriately. I'm using something like `{{ book.title|truncatewords:8}}`

**How can I get the 9th - 16th word? or the 16-24th words? (Something like using the `|slice` filter, but for words).**

I'm trying to avoid playing around with the backend, so the solutions here are too involved: [Is there a Django template filter that handles "...more" and when you click on it, it shows more of the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598460/is-there-a-django-template-filter-that-handles-more-and-when-you-click-on-i/4599202#4599202)

@user3279773 seemingly came up with a solution here involving using `|safe` but didn't post it (and I don't have enough rep to comment a shoutout):

[Django: How to get the truncated portion of "truncatewords"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604574/django-how-to-get-the-truncated-portion-of-truncatewords)

I tried to figure out the |safe solution with various permutations of my code and referenced the link below, but alas, to no avail.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe